# Save user info in a Service or in localStorage in Angular

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, local-storage

If I have a web application with JWT auth, is it better to store user's info in $window.localStorage or in a global common Service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the application that I have seen which use JWT auth save user info in window local storage.